# Redefine google fonts font weight

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Is there any way i can redefine google font faces?
I want to make a google font 300 to be 400, and 500 to be 700 (normal and bold)
I don't wanna search and replace all my scss:es for normal => 300 and bold => 500

Comment: Have a read through these : http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold and http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/11/avoiding-faux-weights-styles-google-web-fonts/  it can be unpredictable.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the weight? If you mean using a Google font with weight 300 (or 500) so that it will be used when CSS declares `normal` (or `bold`) weight, please say that. Sample code would be useful for guessing what you really want.

Comment: I thought the question was as clear as it could be. Sorry if you dont understand it. But i think i got the right answer

Comment: Nick R: I agree, but this is not a new site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Do the following:

```
 <p>Testing</p>
 <i>Testing</i>

    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,500|Roboto+Condensed:300&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext,cyrillic);

    @font-face {
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;

     }

     @font-face {
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: bold;
     }

     body {
         font-family: "Roboto";
         font-weight: normal;
     }

     i {
         font-weight: bold;
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Bold is not a valid font-style property. http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_font_font-style.asp

Comment: Yes, I used it and worked well. I know "Bold" is not a font-style rather it is a font-weight. But when you will define your own font at that case you may define like that way. so try

Comment: Can i specify font? like adding font-family: 'Roboto' ?

Comment: Yes, You can use any name you want.

Comment: This didnt worked for me. I tried without the font-family and it didnt worked.

Comment: If you look here you can see that it doesnt work. Try to change normal to 300 in the body
http://codepen.io/iamrane/pen/nxlwH

Comment: Nope its not the correct weights. Compare how they should look like http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto

Comment: I fixed this by downloading the font. Then it was easier to edit the font so 500 was bold and 300 normal